# Click listeners on canvas shapes in GWT

Tags: gwt, canvas

I was wondering if GWT provides some friendly mechanism to acomplish something as [this demo](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) presents. Maybe not draging, but I need to handle simple clicks on shapes I had previously drawn on the canvas (Images possibly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the GwtCanvas nor the HtmlCanvas. You must manually detect click location and compare that to a managed state of drawn shapes.

It is possible that there is a library for this, but I cannot offer any recommendations.

You could also consider SVG, which *does* support event handlers on drawn items.